# Find total number of files in a sub-folder in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64

I am trying to count the total number of  `jpeg` files located in a folder.

I tried the following:

```
dir|find /e ".jpeg"
```

But it returned the following error.

> FIND: Invalid switch

I am using Windows-7 64 bit.
Please help.

Comment: You are mistaking `find` for `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dir /b /a-d *.jpeg | find /c ".jpeg"
```

http://ss64.com/nt/find.html

Comment: Won't count correctly if an extension is not entirely lowercase. Either `dir /b /a-d *.jpeg | find /i /c ".jpeg"` or better `dir /b /a-d *.jpeg | find /v ""`. The latter counts all lines not containing nothing, i.e. all lines with something.

Answer (score 1):

The command `dir` gives you the count of files at the bottom:

```
dir *.jpeg
```

But if you want to do it in a batch file, you can try this:

```
set count=0 & for %%x in (*.jpg) do @(set /a count+=1 >nul)
echo %count%
```

Comment: Thanks @SomethingDark for taking care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Will work if the language settings are in Enlish.For the prompt:

```
 for /f  %a in ('dir /a:-d "*.jpeg"^|find /i "file(s)"') do echo %a
```

For bat file use:

```
for /f  %%a in ('dir /a:-d "*.jpeg"^|find /i "file(s)"') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

Comment: You do not need "tokens=1" :)